# import data to a database from another database in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have two databases, one is located in localhost, the other one in located in another server.

In python, I want to import some data from database 2 to database 1:

```
  con1 = mdb.connect (host= xx, user=xx, passwd= xx, db= xx) //connect database 1
  cur1 = con1.cursor()
  con2 = mdb.connect (host= xx, user=xx, passwd= xx, db= xx) //connect database 2
  cur2 = con2.cursor()

  query = "update database1.table1 set area = (select database2.table2.area from database2.table2)"

  cur(1 or 2?).execute(query) //Don't know how to solve this problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do cross-server operations like that.

1. Fetch your data from source database (in batches, if it's big)
2. Prepare and send update statements to target database.

Comment: Thank you for your information. But if the case is, two databases are located in the same server. How can I connect to them, and import some data from one to another?

Comment: if both databases are located in the same db process, it's quite easy. Something like `insert into db1.table1 (col1, col2) select col1, col2 from db2.table2;`